# Unable to run/start docker correctly

Tags: docker, coreos

The version of CoreOS I'm using:

```
# uname -am
Linux CoreOSCoreOSStable1465.8.0 4.12.14-coreos #1 SMP Wed Sep 20 22:20:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2673 v3 @ 2.40GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

I started docker via systemctl:

`sudo systemctl start docker`

I verified it is running using ps:

```
root     15845     1  0 16:39 ?        00:00:00 /run/torcx/bin/containerd --
listen unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --shim /run/torcx/bin/containerd-shim --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd --start-timeout 2m
root     15846     1  0 16:39 ?        00:00:00 /run/torcx/bin/dockerd --host=fd:// --containerd=/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --selinux-enabled=true
```

However, when I'm pulling down a container image I'm getting the following error:

```
Using default tag: latest
Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?). Using system 
default: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

I don't see a var/run/docker.sock file, so I'm wondering if that is the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There must have been something wrong with the coreos image I was using.  I tried a different image and docker worked right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

What user are you trying to pull the image with?
They need to be in the docker group

E.g. for linux

```
usermod -a -G docker <user>
```

Comment: I tried to do it with the current user and with root. And i'm getting the same error.

Comment: Did you logout and log back in after adding the user to the docker group?  Try that...